# How do you concisely qualify the direction of viewership?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm making a user content driven website where users watch a stream of said content.  I'm looking for a way to concisely qualify the direction of viewership in the database.  Something more concise than:

"Time spent viewing the stream" and "Time other users have spent viewing my content"

Is there a specific word that qualifies the direction of viewership?  Something like "viewing time" is too vague and doesn't specify if it's the time the user has spent viewing others' content vs. time other users have spent viewing this specific user's content.

Comment: TV folks use the word **airtime**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programing Uploaded: 11.5 hours
Airtime Tally: 246 hours
Complete Viewings: 7

---

Content Watched: 108 hours
Favorite Show: Humor
Most Replays: 4

---

---

After coming up with this I realized it doesn't matter what words you use; it's where they are, and in what box. The *time I've wasted* box, or the *other peoples' time I've wasted* box.

Thanks, @Renae Lider for 'airtime'.